# Format data being read in by CakePHP read() function

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

I am using CakePHP to display an input field that has a "price" variable in it upon editing. Coming from the database this number has a 5 decimal points (for complex calculations).

Without setting the column in the database to be set to only float to 2 points, how would I go about converting this variable to float to only 2 points?

```
<?php echo $form->input('price'); ?>
```

Please let me know if you need any further information from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify a model when you did your $form->create('Model');

You should be able to manipulate the $this->data by specifying the Model and field.

```
<?php echo $form->text('price', 
          array('value' => round($this->data['Model']['price'], 2)));
```

Comment: Yes, I did specify my model. Thank you, this worked like a charm. I am going through and fixing the bollocks that someone else put in here. I don't know why I didn't think to push a 'value' into the array. Again, thank you.